# How do I add back & home button in action bar button for WebView in my android app?

Tags: android, webview, html, back

I made an app which uses WebView to display a mobile website. I have also added ProgressDialog which appears till the page finishes loading. I would like to add a back & home button in the action bar of my app. These buttons should appear when any link is clicked in the home page of the mobile website & disappear when we return to the home page (Similar to Indeed Job search App).

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/actions.html) may help you.

Action bar buttons behaves just like the elements of the overflow menu.
Just add one `<item>` inside your menu resource file with the attribute `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` or `app:showAsAction="always"`.

According to android dev site your xml should look like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- "Mark Favorite", should appear as action button if possible -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_go_back"
        android:title="@string/action_back"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Then you have to attach a listener for that button: just handle as if it was in the overflow menu. So you have to override `onOptionsItemSelected` adding something like `if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {mWebView.goBack();}`

Here's the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_back:
            if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            }

        // ... other cases ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `onClickListeners` on both **Back** button and **Home** Button.

**1**.For Back Button implementation.

```
backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                               if(webView.canGoBack()){ 
                                  webView.goBack();
                                 }

                        }
                });
```

**2**.For Home Button implementation.

```
homeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                                while(webView.canGoBack())
                                        {
                                                webView.goBack();

                                        }

                        }
                });
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply set the visibility of these two menu actions depending on the current URL on URL change:

```
actionBack.setVisibility(yourWebView.getUrl().equals("www.yourHomePage.com") ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Could you tell me where to exactly place this? What is actionBack (MenuItem or Up Button in toolbar)?